# Copying column from one table to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a music store in Visual Studio. I want to create a database table for genre. I want the `Album` table to refer to the `Genre` table. So these two tables have one to many relationship. The `Album` table already has a `genre` column so I figure add that to a new table I create but I've been unsuccessful so far.

Any assistant would be appreciated. I tried something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.GenreTable 
    SELECT Genre 
    FROM Albums.dbo.mytable
```

But I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you really wish to insert _only_ the `Genre` column from the second table?  Please include table structure for both tables, and maybe also include some sample data.

Comment: I have tested your query its working fine you need to share the error your are receiving while you execute the query

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
INSERT INTO dbo.GenreTable
(
    Genre
)
SELECT 
     Genre 
FROM 
     Albums.dbo.mytable
```

Tested working flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Copy only some columns from one table into another table like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.GenreTable(Genre)
SELECT Genre FROM Albums.dbo.mytable

INSERT INTO dbo.GenreTable(column1,column2, ....)
SELECT (column1,column2, ....) FROM Albums.dbo.mytable
```

Copy all columns from one table to another table like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.GenreTable
SELECT * FROM Albums.dbo.mytable
```